# Adding messages without text in Django's messages framework

Tags: django, django-messages

Sometimes I would like to trigger a message to the user with the message's text defined in the client-side JS code. I am using the message framework's [tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages#message-tags) to differentiate between the different messages in JS.

Unfortunately, it seems to me that when I call `messages.add_message` with the message text set to `None` and a number of tags, the message is discarded. Is there are a way to send a message without text in Django?

Comment: I'm not sure about it and i can't try it now, but would an empty string (instead of `None`) work?

Comment: `""` and `None` both don't work unfortunately. I guess the easiest way is to simply supply some placeholder message but I feel like the messages framework should support messages without text.